# How to abstract Doctrine 2 entity fields?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, interface

I have a few (Doctrine 2) entities that have similar fields, for instance `foo`, `value` and `datetime`. I would like to take advantage of this, and define a custom `FooEntityRepository` with shared methods.

A custom `EntityRepository` is easily created, but how does one force a entity using this repository to have the `foo`,`value`,`datetime` fields? Maybe one of the entities stores the same value not in `foo`, but `bar`. I want to anticipate on this.

I could define an interface with `getFooFieldName`,`getValueFieldName` that the entities in question should implement, but is this the way to go? Should I in this case go as far as actually letting the repository "evaluate" if the functions return valid field names?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define custom EntityRepository and then extend it by custom entity repositories for every child entity of the abstract entity. Then, all the shared methods will be available for all the entities.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well, the problem in that case is that the EntityRepository is not really general anymore. Methods like `getFooFieldName` in the repository then still have to be runtime validated. Additionally I create high coupling between the Entity and the Repository, something that I don't think is favourable.